# How to make a permission system in symfony like the following?

Tags: user-permissions, symfony4

I wanna build a simple permission system  using symphony 4 that has the following properties:

- there are several possible roles for users (SUPER_ADMIN, ADMIN, USER,QUEST)
- SUPER_ADMIN users can grant view or edit&delete permissions for a given entity  to a certain user no mater what his role is

What is the best solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please, start reading these documentations to figure out some basics :

[SF4 Authorization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html)

[SF4 Security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)

[SF4 Voters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html)